# gradle rootspec filesMatching using pattern

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to manipulate few files within the war like below

```
war{
    rootSpec.filesMatching('**/WEB-INF/spring/root-context*.xml'){ detail ->
            // change the name of detail file
        }

}
```

For some reason pattern matching does not work . Only Exact match works like below

```
 war{
        rootSpec.filesMatching('**/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml'){ detail ->
                // change the name of detail file
            }

    }
```

I have different files in this folder which starts with 'root-context' and I want to include only one of those files in the war.

Am I doing anything wrong in the filesMatching call ?

Comment: If `filesMatching ` takes regex as parameter, try to change it to `'**/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.*.xml'`

Comment: Thanks - But it did not work .

Answer (score 0):

Only below check works .

Changed my logic accordingly.

```
war{
    rootSpec.filesMatching('**/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml'){ detail ->
            // change the name of detail file
        }

}
```